# Arabic encoding for Cascading Dropdown Menu [PHP/AJAX]

Tags: php, ajax, encoding, menu, arabic

I have auto sales website using php and the templates (tpl) and controllers in admin  and includes folders.

The area to focus is the CARS search form . When a user chooses an option from the (MAKE) dropdown menu, that choice drives the (MODEL) dropdown menu. The logic behind it works, but I am having problems with the encoding in Arabic characters as you can see in:

[image]

The site uses the following Ajax files:
xajax_core.js
xajax_core_uncompressed.js

and other files

Comment: make sure that your connection to database is UTF8 if using mysql, this  can be done by adding a query "set names 'utf8'" before the retrieve query

Comment: all tables in database are encoded as (utf-genral-ci ) or smthing like that

Answer (score 0):

are you using function [utf8_encode](http://php.net/utf8_encode) ?

this function in php ONLY translate latin to UTF8, it will break arabic characters

Comment: so do i change the database encoding to latin1 ?

Comment: this will simply kill arabic letters completely!, you have to check what kind of functions are processing the text before being displayed in browser, usually functions meant to escape characters for xml like the one above are the problem point when everything else is right